# Accessing Virtualbox host-only guests via VPN (tun0)

Tags: linux, virtualbox, routing, openvpn

My question seems to be the exact same as [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122118/accessing-virtualbox-guest-via-vpn), but the solution didn’t work for me.

#### Set-up:

I have one Ubuntu machine acting as a Virtualbox host and OpenVPN server, and several Virtualbox guests inside the host-only network `vboxnet1 172.16.0.0/24`.

I can connect to the Ubuntu machine from my macOs host which gets the address `10.8.0.2` with VPN, I can also ping the server’s host-only address `172.16.0.1`.

#### Problem

I’d like to access a VM located inside the host-only network at `172.16.0.3`, but all my pings have timed out.

#### What I tried

- Pushing the subnet to all clients in OpenVPN config with `push "route 172.16.0.0 255.255.255.0"`
- Enabling IP forwarding according to the solution in the link.

`cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` returns `1`. Still doesn’t work.

- Running `tcpdump` on both ends show that my ICMP requests from `10.8.0.2` are indeed reaching `172.16.0.3` and `172.16.0.3` has been sending ICMP replies back. But `tcpdump` on `vboxnet1` on the Ubuntu host doesn't show any of the reply packets. Probably dropped somewhere in the host-only network?

#### Question

What do I need to do to allow connected VPN clients to access virtual machines in the host-only network?

Many thanks in advance. I’ve been banging my head on the wall for the past few days for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After `ssh`ing inside the VM and changing the default gateway with `ip route change default via 172.16.0.1 dev eth1`, I’m able to ping the VM from my VPN client. That’s the step I was missing.